# a short way to specify a data validator

Tags: python, pydantic

I'd like to ask if describing a data validator only by a so called [generic alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) could lead to problems.

---

A validator is basically a function/callable. Given an arbitrary input value it should either return a valid value (possibly coerced) or raise an exception.

Let's take for example a function accepting such validator. A simple case would be:

```
foo(..., validator=int)  # it produces either an integer or it raises
```

If the expected data format is not so trivial - for instance a list of integers, it could be called with:

```
foo(..., validator=pydantic.TypeAdapter(list[int]).validate_python)
```

But maybe this is better readable and more similar to `validator=int`:

```
foo(..., validator=list[int])
```

In such case the `foo` function would be responsible to wrap arguments like `list[int]` into a `TypeAdapter`

```
if isinstance(validator, types.GenericAlias):
    validator = pydantic.TypeAdapter(validator).validate_python
```

I'm just no so sure about more complicated cases. Could this introduce some unwanted behaviour?